# Missing parameter in Ajax post to Asmx

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services, asmx

I'm trying to send the string `File` to my asmx service and I keep getting the following error:

```
    Message: Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: File
    StackTrace   
at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters) at 
System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\\r\\n   at 
System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\\r\\n   at 
System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)\",\"ExceptionType\":\"System.InvalidOperationException\"}
```

Here's the JS

```
function AJAXActionPostData(service, operation, File, callback, async)
{
    if (!async) { async = false; }
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/API/Service.asmx/operation',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        async: async,
        data: "{ 'File': '" + File + "' }",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (msg) { if (msg) { callback(msg.d); } },
        error: ErrorHandler
    });
}
```

when passed into the function above `file` has a value of "test\r\n" Could the escape characters be messing with it?

Service code

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public bool UploadCSV(string id, string File)
    {
        string testfile = File;
        return true;
    }
```

No other errors are thrown, just the `File` not having a value.
I've tried various things but cannot understand what I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try sending the `data` as a plain object:

```
data: { 'File': File },
```

Or as a string:

```
data: 'File=' + File,
```

At the moment you're doing a little of both which won't work.

Comment: Well noted @Rory McCrossan +1 :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! "data: {'File': File}" throws invalid JSON primitive exception

Comment: "data: 'File=' + File" Worked perfectly with datatype text! I'm guessing my JSON just isn't formatted correctly or referenced correctly, thanks

Comment: @Rory I've got the same error, but I've got three variables, do I concatenate them with a '&'