# how to send a serialized string to asp?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, web-services, getjson

I'm getting a headache trying to parse an MDX member from a `$.get` request through to a .asmx file;

initially my request looked like this;
`$.get("/" + source + ".asmx/FilterData", {strKeyval: queryName, controlID: currentID, filterString: filterString},`

where filterString's value is; `[Product].[Product].[Dept No].&[123]`

I was getting a server side error though and figured it was the ampersand, so on the advice of  Rory in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618748/missing-parameter-in-ajax-post-to-asmx#), I tried the `escape()` function, but now I'm getting this error from the asmx file, because of the `%` symbols;

> Parser: The following syntax error occurred during parsing: Invalid token, Line 1, offset 499, %

how do I make asp accept this? I never have this problem with php!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after tearing and wrecking my brain, I found a simpler solution than I'd have thought would have worked:

I removed the `escape()` function entirely as well as any serialization I used before and simply replaced the `&`s with html encoded ampersands like this;

```
filterString = filterString.replace("&", "\\u0026");
```

works nicely, I wish ASP and Microsoft would stop being so anal, they should deal with security risks rather than avoid it

Answer (score 2):

You can configure your asmx service to accept POST requests:

In web.config:

```
<webServices>
    <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
</webServices>
```

And instead of $.get use $.post. If use post the data will be sent in the request's body and you won't need to escape the '&'

Comment: they already accept post requests. . .please post a comment next time you think a seperate, related issue was the problem

Comment: good point though, but this was me adding a feature to what had been running in production for almost 6 months, I don't know if they'd have allowed a database search request to be done in post, woulda opened up space for break-ins